# How to maintain parent div :hover CSS style when clicking on child element

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a div that contains a span button such that the div is only visible when hovered. That works fine already, but when the span button is clicked to open up its associated menu, the button is no longer visible in the background of the menu. If I click outside of the menu around where the span button should be (basically within the parent div), the button is immediately visible again. From my understanding, clicking the span button makes it so that the div is no longer in a hover state, so the styling for it is no longer applied. I've tried including the :focus and :focus-within selectors to this style too, but it doesn't seem like clicking the span button is triggering it. Is there any way to keep this parent div visible when its child button has been clicked, preferably with CSS?

```
<div class="menu-button-container" style="visibility:hidden">
  <span class="menu-button">
    <i class="btn btn-menu"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
&:hover, &:focus, &:focus-within {
  .menu-button-container {
    visibility: visible
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve??

```css
.menu-button-container{
  display:none
}

button:focus + .menu-button-container {
    display:block
  }
```

```html
<span class="menu-button">
    <button class="btn btn-menu">Hello</button>
 
<div class="menu-button-container">
  hello world
</div>
 </span>
```